# How To Use GraphQL To get Product Entity?

Tags: magento2.3

I want to built custom extension to get product entity using GraphQL.

I referred below links.

https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/get-product-collection-using-graphql-magento-2/

https://amasty.com/blog/magento-2-api-updates-graphql/

Still if anyone have good reference extension then please help me.